# Что за приведение типа в аргументе bind?

Tags: сокеты, c, c++

```
struct sockaddr_in stSockAddr;
...
bind(SocketFD,(const struct sockaddr *)&stSockAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

Зачем нужно приводить stSockAddr к (const struct sockaddr *) ?

Comment: Просто, потому что в прототипе функции `bind` прописан тип `const struct sockaddr *` 

(`sockaddr_in` это частный случай `struct sockaddr`, посмотрите в /usr/include/... socket.h, in.h и т.д. (правда, там довольно сложная, зависящая от архитектуры структура файлов)).

Comment: @avp, так а что происходит? Вот есть объект sockaddr_in, и есть в нем 4 поля, потом его приводят к sockaddr, и в нем становится 2 поля, но а каким образом обрезаются ненужные поля и остаются нужные? Может, есть готовые примеры где-то, в которых показана реализация, как это явным образом выглядит?

Comment: @xinakapu, в данном случае никто никакие поля не выбрасывает.

Вы просто говорите компилятору, что по заданному адресу находится структура типа `struct sockaddr` и **ничего более этого**. Реально  в функцию **передается адрес памяти**. На самом деле, как трактовать данные (реальные цепочки бит) зависит от вызываемой функции.

По первому полю `bind` определит, какую из внутренних реализаций (IPv4, IPv6 и т.д.) надо вызывать и передаст ей Ваш адрес. А уже та будет трактовать эти данные, как она запрограммирована.

Comment: Просто надо различать "реальные" приведения типа, вида:

     (double)1 / 2  // получим 0.5

когда компилятор преобразует битовое представление числа из одного типа (у на из `int`) в другое (в `double`)

или

     long l = 123456789;
     int x = (unsigned char)l; // в x младший байт из l

когда меняется размер целого типа,

от приведений типа указателя (я бы назвал это "фиктивным" приведением (как "по-науке" его называют -- не помню)). 

В последнем случае (как у нас с `bind`) на самом деле ничего (кроме "обмана" компилятора) с битовым представлением переменной не происходит.

Comment: @avpСпасибо, теперь понятно. А такой обман компилятора может привести к каким-нибудь проблемам? Я вспомнил, что читал в какой-то книге об этом моменте с указателями и там говорилось, что есть какие-то проблемы, но я их не вспомнил.

Comment: IMHO это будут проблемы с записью циклов по массивам таких структур. Например:

    struct x1 { int a, b; }; 
    struct x2 { int a, b; double z; };

    struct x2 a[10] = { ... };
    f((struct x1 *)a, sizeof(a[0]), 5);

В функцию, которая ожидает массив типа `struct x1`, придется передавать размер фактической структуры  и писать цикл так:

    f (struct x1 *p, size_t ps, int n) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        f2((struct x1 *)((char *)p + i * ps)); // вместо f2(p[i]);
    }

Это для передачи в `f2 (struct x1 *)` правильного адреса `struct x1`, к которой приводится `struct x2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сокеты устроены хитро, но красиво. Есть одна базовая структура и несколько "наследников". Их разница - начинаются они одинаково, а вот концовки - различные. Тут все, как с классами, только вручную. Посмотрим на определение этих двух структур:

```
struct sockaddr {
        ushort  sa_family;
        char    sa_data[14];
};

struct sockaddr_in {
        short   sin_family;
        u_short sin_port;
        struct  in_addr sin_addr;
        char    sin_zero[8];
};
```

(Честно скопированы с сайта [майкрософта](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx), хотя могли быть скопированы и в других местах.)

То есть если это было бы на классах, то первый был базовым, а второй - наследником с двумя дополнительными полями.

Теперь ближе к цели. Некоторые функции работы с сокетами - базовые, они работают с просто сокетами. А есть прицельные - например, работающие  с tcp/udp сокетами (есть и другие типы сокетов - например, файловые дескрипторы, пайпы и другое). Базовые функции работают с базовой структурой, прицельные - со своей структурой. Так как начало структуры совпадает, то базовым функциям "побоку" на концовку, главное знать размер (на случай, если нужно скопировать, передать куда-то дальше).

`bind` является такой базовой функцией.

Так как с++ является типизированным языком, а на структуры "наследованные вручную", то нужно приводить "к базовой структуре".

Comment: Спасибо, с причинам стало теперь понятно. А вот как работает это приведение объекта одной структуры к объекту другой? Где-то читал ваши развернутые ответы по этому поводу, но уже забыл и не могу найти. То есть когда и какой неявно вызывается конструктор или что-то в этом роде. Кстати, на си такой код не будет же работать?

Comment: Структура в памяти - это просто массив байт, не более, не менее. Обращение к полю структуры - это просто обращение к некой части этого массива. Поэтому, на самом деле можно подменить структуру, главное, чтобы поля правильно "наложились". Поэтому главное правильно разложить поля - вот и все приведение.